# Orchard: Link to Content Item

Tags: c#, .net, content-management-system, orchardcms

I need some help with one issue on Orchard.

I've done some links on header, sidebar and footer using Navigation feature but now I need to change the layout to H1 only on sidebar.

Is there any way to do that or some module/widget to create links for documents (content item) besides Navigation?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can list content items with the [Projector module](http://orchardproject.net/Tags/Projector) (as widgets too). You can also just add links to an Html Widget and place it into an arbitrary zone and layer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I need one way to put a single link for one document, not a list. Do you know if it is possible?

Comment: If you really want an automatic link (and a hand-coded one I've described isn't sufficient for you) than I don't know of any solution (except for displaying a 1 long Projector list).